# Why we need to explicitly return list in a Apache Beam ParDo Function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have below code,which perform some operation on CSV file.

```
class SplitRow(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    return  [element.split(',')]

class FilterCardioPatients(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    if element[3] == 'cardio':
      return [element]
 
class PairPatients(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    return [(element[1], 1)]
class Counting(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    (key, values) = element
    return [(key, sum(values))]
 

p1 = beam.Pipeline()

visit_count = (
 
  p1
  |beam.io.ReadFromText(inputs_pattern)
  
  |beam.ParDo(SplitRow())
  |beam.Map(print)
  # |beam.ParDo(FilterCardioPatients())
  # |beam.ParDo(PairPatients())
  # |beam.GroupByKey()
  # | beam.ParDo(Counting())
 
  # |beam.io.WriteToText('parddo_output.txt')
)

p1.run()
```

The output is:

['2984641', 'Emily', '35', 'cardio', '1/9/21']

['9454384', 'Riikka', '86', 'ortho', '21-07-2021']

But,when I change definiton of SplitRow as:

```
class SplitRow(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    return  element.split(',')
```

It gives output as:

2984641

Emily

35

cardio

1/9/21

9454384

Riikka

86

ortho

21-07-2021

9266396

Why we need to explicitly return the list of split element.
***The python split function itself returns a list.***

Answer (score 2):

The `DoFn`'s process method is like [FlatMap](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/flatmap/): it returns zero or more output elements per input (each of which becomes a distinct element in the output PCollection).

It may be more natural to use `yield` rather than `return` which creates the outer iterable implicitly, e.g.

```
class SplitRow(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    yield element.split(',')

class FilterCardioPatients(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    if element[3] == 'cardio':
      yield element

class PairPatients(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    yield element[1], 1

class Counting(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    (key, values) = element
    yield key, sum(values)
```

As a side note, for this particular (associative, commutative) aggregation, you may want to consider using [CombineFns](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine) which can push part of the computation pre-shuffle.

Answer (score -1):

Both functions are valid and useful, they just do different things.

It's the same as the difference between `[[1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7]]` and `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. One gives you a list-of-lists that allows grouping, while the second is a flattened list without subgroups.

You would use `[element.split(',')]` if you want the values in each line to stay together as one unit, as is typically the case with CSV. If you run it through another DoFn, that Fn will first see `[1,2]` then `[3,4,5]`, etc.

You would use `element.split(',')` if you don't care about the original line structure and just want each token. This is more common to e.g. count words in a text, because you don't care which line the word was originally on. If you run it through another DoFn, that Fn will first see `1`, then `2`, then `3`, etc.